# Box2d on authoritative server for Unity client

Tags: unity, c++, physics, box2d, multiplayer

I'm creating a multiplayer platform and shooting game in unity, using unity2d's own physics system (box2d).

But the truth is that I am quite lost in the creation of an authoritative server in c ++.
I have quite clear and experience in the use of socket for communication between client and server, I do not know how to approach the issue of simulating the physics of my game on the server so that it decides the positions/movements of the clients.

Can anyone guide me to use box2d on the server, as I simulate the game on the server? Is this a good option or would it be better to implement my own game physics than to use the non-deterministic engine?

Thank you very much and sorry for my level of English

Comment: Why not use Unity as your server, so you have the same implementation running both the server and client, rather than needing to build these aspects twice?

Comment: Do you currently have an authoritative main loop on your server simulating your game?

Comment: @DMGregory Thank you very much for the reply. It is a very good idea and easy to implement, but I find 2 questions. How to run multiple game scenes simultaneously? And above all, will this be efficient for many players?

Comment: You can use position or physics layers to separate different scenes, or just run multiple instances of your Unity server process, just like you would with any other server program. Will it be efficient? The only answer to that is profiling. You have no guarantee your hand-rolled code will be efficient either, so you always have to test it to see if it's meeting your needs, or identify bottlenecks to fix.

Comment: @Vaillancourt My idea is to create a thread for each game where I can simulate the physics of the clients' game, but I don't know how I can replicate the physics of unity in my c ++ server with box2D and I don't find much documentation on this either ... :(

Comment: @DMGregory The truth is that I have been exploring possibilities for a long time and your comment has made me see a great opportunity, I see that you also understand about this topic. Thank you

Do you think that if I really use unity as a server, I could program the whole server part (authentication, database, matchmaking, etc.) from this or it would be better to use a server from another language like c ++ and leave unity only for physics and realtime aspects.

Comment: That's a "what technology to use" question, which we don't answer here. I'd spin it around: do you have any evidence that Unity C# would be incapable of handling those needs? If you find signs of a problem here, by all means, post a question to ask how to solve it. But there's no point in worrying if you don't have any indication of a real problem to solve yet.

Comment: @DMGregory 
I perfectly understand. Explore more the idea of ​​using unity as a server to see if it suits my needs. Thank you very much for your help